# Characters Moving Along a Spaceship Unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

So essentially I am trying to make a game where you have characters moving inside a spaceship where the idea is these characters go to different areas to preform different tasks around the ship (such as piloting or manning a weapon).

[image][image]

I am currently having an issue with the interaction between the characters and the ship where the ship is being effected by the players when they move and starts to slide out of control. This happens seemingly at very large masses (in the photos the ship is 10000 and the player 10).

This is what happens when a character moves up.
[image]

I want the movement of the players and the movement of the ship to act semi independently where the characters move along with the ship but can move freely inside without it really effecting the ship at all. I tried using a fixed joint but the ship still flips out.

Comment: Is there a reason for the character are not children of the ship ?

Comment: @ThomasFinet They both have rigidbodies and I need to detect collisions between the characters and the ship's individual parts.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to fix that:

1. Your ship does not need rigidbody, remove it so it wont move at all (only one of the Colliders needs Rigidbody to detect collision, so lets Player have Rigidbody and not the ship, I suppose that is your case)
2. Your ship rigidbody does not need to rotate. Set Constraints in your ships Rigidbody: Freeze Rotation X = true, Freeze Rotation Z = true, and probably Freeze Rotation Y = true too (depends on case)
3. Set your ships Rigidbody to isKinematic = true if you want it to be controlled by script not physics.